# Destructuring array in react/javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, destructuring

I have array [image]

as you can see, it has 4 elements (created_at, first_name, id, last_name).

My question is, how do I destructure it into an array that has 2 elements(id, name)

(name should be first_name + last_name)

Comment: Kindly post the real javascript data rather than image from console.

Comment: What you have is an array of 2 objects, each object containing 4 keys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `map`:

```
arr.map(({id, first_name, last_name}) => { return {id, name: first_name + ' ' + last_name}})
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [{
    "id": 100,
    "first_name": "first_name_1",
    "last_name": "last_name_1",

},
{
    "id": 101,
    "first_name": "first_name_2",
    "last_name": "last_name_2",
}
];

console.log(arr.map(({id, first_name, last_name}) => { return {id, name: first_name + ' ' + last_name}}))
```

Comment: Maybe add a space between `first_name` and `last_name`

Comment: I wrote the same answer but before I pressed post this answer came in haha, upvoted this

Comment: You can also wrap the object in parenthesis so you don't need `return` keyword

Answer (score 1):

You can use **map** to get the new array as your requirements. Code look likes

```
const data = [
  {created_at:"2020-01-05", first_name:"Sadio", id:1, last_name:"Marne"},
  {created_at:"2020-01-05", first_name:"Mohamed", id:2, last_name:"Salah"},
  {created_at:"2020-01-05", first_name:"Palash", id:3, last_name:"Kanti"},
  {created_at:"2020-01-05", first_name:"Tuhin", id:4, last_name:"Saha"},
  ]

let newArray=data.map(res=>{
  return {id:res.id, name:res.first_name+' '+res.last_name}
});

console.log(newArray)
```